# canvas html not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawable

I have been working on this code, I seem to have created the function correctly but when I run it it is not actually drawing anything? What am I missing?

I tried different forms of drawing for line, arc, triangle and rectangle to see if it was one of them not working but neither of them seem to work.

Thank you!

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Hwk8 Drawable</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function draw()
            {
                shapeSelected = document.index.shapeChosen.value;
                //creating canvas object
                canvas = document.getElementByID("myCanvas");
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,0)";
                
                if (shapeSelected == "line")
                {
                    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
                    ctx.lineTo(200,100);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                else if (shapeSelected.equals("arc"))
                {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                else if (shapeSelected === "triangle")
                {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(75,0);
                    ctx.lineTo(150,100);
                    ctx.lineTo(0,100);
                    ctx.lineTo(75,0);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                else if (shapeSelected.equals("rectangle"))
                {
                    ctx.strokeRect(50,50,50,50);
                    ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action ="index.jsp">
            <h2>Choose what you want to draw</h2>
             <select name="shapeChosen" required onChange="draw()">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Shape</option>
                <option value="line">Line</option>
                <option value="arc">Arc</option>
                <option value="triangle">Triangle</option>
                <option value="square">Square</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your console indicate?...Use debugger and check if draw() function is getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByName()` to get an element by `name`, and `document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`. And use `==` (or `===`) and not `.equals()`:

```
function draw()
{
    shapeSelected = document.getElementsByName("shapeChosen")[0].value;
    //creating canvas object
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ...
}
```

Also your last statement needs to be `(shapeSelected =="square")` and not `(shapeSelected == "rectangle")` as in the `<option>` it's defined as: `<option value="square">Square</option>`.

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j8uzkjdw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your code

1) You need to change the syntax for selecting an option value

2) You have written wrong syntax of getElementById ()

Please check the corrected your example in  **[Corrected `Your Code` Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upardhi/57527bof/embedded/result/)**